# how do i give permission of updating business hours to a normal user other than system administrator?

Tags: businesshours

Is there a way we can give a normal user with the previlage of updating business hours and holidays in salesforce?

Any supporting URL would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

PF following option(s) to achieve it.

- **option 1:**

in profile settings "manage business hours holiday" permission is available for any custom profile ,we can enable that and please make sure "View Setup & Configuration" permission also enabled there as "Holiday" object is available under company profile settings.

- **option 2:**

we can create separate holiday custom object in Salesforce and make it available for user In UI in separate tab. we can refer this "custom holiday object " in code wherever its required.

My recommendation should be with option(1) as we will be able to re-use salesforce standard methods for holiday calculation in code.

[image]

Comment: Better to use `Permission Sets` rather the custom profiles.